# Bullet Image Auto-Sizing

Tags: html, image, css, bulletedlist

I am formatting with CSS3.  I have an excessively large image that I am using for bullets.  I want the bullet to automatically resize to the size of the font.  Am I able to do this?

If not, (darn) how would I set the image-bullet to a particular size? (Such as 12 height, and auto-scaled width)

```
    ul {
        list-style-image: url('rectangular_bullet_image.jpg')
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use a *large* image for a list bullet? But if you want it to be resizable, I would suggest using a custom font or Unicode character and `li:before`.

Comment: Avoid list-style-image - it goes you no control over image placement or size. Use a CSS background instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to scale to the height of the li, then use Mihnea solution.

If you want it to scale to the font size, use

```
ul li {
    padding-left: 20%;
    background: url('rectangular_bullet_image.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: auto 1em; 
}
```

where the last size (1em) refers to the size of the font. So, if you want it to be slightly larger than the font, set 1.2em

Note that the 2 solutions are aproximately the same if the li's have only 1 line.

It's for the multi-line li's that there is a diference.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 20%;

    background: url('rectangular_bullet_image.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 20% 100%; 
}
```

heres's a fiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/YUjdz/1/